# How to run mongodb server in Github Codespace container?

Tags: mongodb, containers, github-codespaces

I'm trying to setup a Codespace container so that I'll be able to use MongoDB server. Simple installation described on the [MongoDB website](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) doesn't work. The installation succeeds however I'm not able to use `systemctl` to run the service. On the other hand the command `service --status-all` shows there's no `mongod` available.

I've found following topic: [How do I connect to MongoDB, running in Github codespaces, using MongoDB Compass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70296667/how-do-i-connect-to-mongodb-running-in-github-codespaces-using-mongodb-compass). It looks like someone configured MongoDB as a tool built-in into container. However reading the question further I found that the goal there is to connect with Mongo on local machine from the container.

Is it even possible to install MongoDB in the Codespace, like any other piece of software, and then run it?

Comment: Please re-read the "How do I" topic again. It is about how to connect Compas (a desktop electron mongo UI) to the database hosted in the Codespace.  The OP had no problems running mongo in Codespace, and I don't recall any when I was experimenting with client config there. It was literally copy-paste from OPs  configs.

Comment: Ok, you're right. However the docker-compose.yml file is not generated after codespace creation. What's more, it seems like there's no support for Mongo DB. According to the help website: https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces I should be able to create a config file for Python & Mongo DB. That option is not present in the list when I'm trying to configure my codespace.

Comment: Well, if the vendor removed the option, than it is not supported anymore, yes?